# Cannot upgrade Android Studio from 3.5.0 to 3.5.1

Tags: 18.04, android-studio

I am not able to upgrade. During the upgrade the following error is thrown:

[image]

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.3. Android Studio originally installed via `umake`.

This behavior can be systematically reproduced on my machine.

Does anyone have any suggestion to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade was possible after cleaning the contents of `sdk/build-tools` folder.